# How to handle Windows Forms Textbox's AutoSize hardcoded to true?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, textbox, containers, autosize

I'm writing custom containers for Windows Forms with automatic layouting. Microsoft documentation suggests to use the following code to honor autosize property of controls:

```
if (control.AutoSize)
{
    control.Size = control.GetPreferredSize(parentDisplayRectangle.Size);
}
```

The problem is that textbox seems to have AutoSize hardcoded to true and calling mentioned code on it ends like this:

[image: Autosized textbox]

How should I approach evaluating preferred size for textboxes in my custom container controls?

---

**Update**: after visit to Referencesource.

There's a helpful comment in DefaultLayout class:

```
    // Loop through the AutoSized controls and expand them if they are smaller than
    // their preferred size.  If expanding the controls causes overlap, bump the overlapped
    // control if it is AutoRelocatable.
```

It seems like the idea of AutoSize is to allow control to be bigger than designed, and not actually precisely the size returned from GetPreferredSize.

This is to be confirmed though.

Source: [DockAndAnchorLayout.cs, class DefaultLayout](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Layout/DockAndAnchorLayout.cs,e3503926a43d6ad4)

Comment: That code depends on the type of control and on the use of a *custom* LayoutEngine. In this case, `control.Size = control.GetPreferredSize(parentDisplayRectangle.Size);`, is used to evaluate the height of a control. Controls that expose the AutoSize property already handle their Layout internally (you can override it in the `OnLayout` method or with a custom engine). The size of other controls is better handled anchoring/docking. You are, apparently, designing a custom LayoutEngine, what for is up to you. Autosizing an input control (which usually hides the property) may not be a good idea.

Comment: @Jimi, thanks for input. I believe, that matter is a little bit more complex - take Panel, for instance: if you put on it a label with AutoSize, it adjusts its width and height basing on content. But if you put a textbox, it adjusts only its height, leaving width unchanged. Obviously I can do `if (control is TextBox)` (or similar), but it seems to be more hacking than a real solution.

Comment: @Jimi, And yes, I didn't expressed it explicitly, but indeed I'm writing my own LayoutEngine. Since Windows Forms are opensourced, maybe I'll simply take a look, how Panel's layout manager does its work? If I find something helpful, I'll post it here.

Comment: Read the notes left in [TextBoxBase.AutoSize](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,257). Controls that handle the AutoSize property, evaluate the current LayoutEngine - to test whether is the default instance of the engine, then call [SetSelfAutoSizeInDefaultLayout](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Layout/CommonProperties.cs,474). You custom LayoutEngine needs to consider this behavior if you want to override the default's.

Comment: The Label control, for example, [overrides GetPreferredSizeCore](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Label.cs,1282) (see also the note on `GetPreferredSize` (one-method up)). TextBoxBase hides the property and use the AutoSize *model* to adjust its height (after having tested other properties, like `Multiline`, `Dock` and `Anchor`).